# How can i show my Magazine App in Google Play in News & Magazines Categories

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed an Android Magazine Application and Successfully Published.
How can i make my app, visible to users on News & Magazines Categories. Presently it is visible only in applications but Google Play has a Separate Tab "News & Magazines Categories" to only search for News & Magazines.

You can view the Tab in the Below Link.

https://play.google.com/about/

Comment: Not a question for SO. Try Quora or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, you can publish apps under the News and Magazines category under Apps category. This would be [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/NEWS_AND_MAGAZINES). The content directly under Magazines tab is published by various Media houses, and is accessed via the Google Play Magazines App.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have selected the Category as "News&Magazines". So, to show my app visible in Magazines Tab do i need to use Android Magazine Maker to build my magazine?

Comment: Per my understanding, you would need to publish Magazine content itself, and not an App, and you should be able to use the appropriate tools to create your magazine in the forms acceptable to Google Play Store. For more information on this you can reach out to Google here -> https://support.google.com/magazinepartners/contact/interest?hl=en&rd=2 . Also, if this addresses your question, then please accept the answer. Lastly, StackOverflow questions are expected to be much more well researched than your original question.